# How to use AWS Video Rekognition with an unauthenticated identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

i have followed the steps of the documentation but i received:

`User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/CognitoRkUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/CognitoRkUnauth_Role`

The code fails en `NotificationChannel`. Without this i received the jobId correctly

```
var params = {
      Video: {
        S3Object: {
          Bucket: 'mybucket',
          Name: 'myvideoa1.mp4'
        }
      },
      ClientRequestToken: 'LabelDetectionToken',
      MinConfidence: 70,
      NotificationChannel: {
        SNSTopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:RekognitionVideo',
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/CognitoRkUnauth_Role'
      },
      JobTag: "DetectingLabels"
    }
```

I set configuration to CognitoRkUnauth_Role instead of a iam user. Translation worked doing this.

In `RoleArn` I created another Role but it fails too.

I am not the root user.

I know I need to give more information but if someone can guide me, i will start again the configuration.

I am beginner in aws and i dont understand several things at all.

*(english is not my first language)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to create a new User. I think there is no reason for doing what i wanted to do :p